# I want to insert my session variable value in the database.

Tags: php, laravel, session

I want to insert my session variable value in the database. i have tried this code but its not working
$uid=$_SESSION['userid'];
$image->U_id = Input::get($uid);
what should i do?

Comment: If you are using laravel, use `Session` class to access the session. Do not directly use the `$_SESSION` variable

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION['userid'];` doesn't work in Laravel.

Try this:

```
$userid = Session::get('userid'); // this is the way to get laravel session value
// save it in database
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the variable stored in `$uid`, there is no reason to call `Input::get()`.

So just do something likes this.

```
$uid=$_SESSION['userid'];

$image = new Image;
$image->U_id = $uid;

$image->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your aim is to achieve with this, but you can also store the sessions in the database with very little configuration if that's what you're after, Laravel already supports this.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session)